# How can I remove transparency from the widget that overlays the other?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create an expandable widget that overlays a ListView. However, this widget is transparent, and I want to not be able to see the part of the ListView that is under it.

Above picture is demo of problem.
[image: transparency demo]

Here is the problem code

```
class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  final lvController = ScrollController();
  ExpandableController exController = ExpandableController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    //  controller = new ExpandableController(initialExpanded: true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void listenScrolling() {
    if (lvController.position.atEdge) {
      final isTop = lvController.position.pixels < 50;

      if (isTop) {
        print("scrolled to top");
        setState(() {
          exController.toggle();
        });
      }
    } else if (lvController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.reverse &&
        exController.expanded) {
      setState(() {
        exController.toggle();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SafeArea(
        child: ExpandableNotifier(
            initialExpanded: true,
            child: Container(
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: sappBar(context),
                    body: Column(children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
                        Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Expandable(
                                  collapsed: Container(),
                                  expanded: testCard(),
                                ))),
                        buildList()
                      ]))
                    ])))));
  }

  Widget testCard() {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Card(
          child: Text(
              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium."),
          color: Colors.white,
        ));
  }

  Widget buildList() => ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      controller: lvController,
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
              title: Center(
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
          )));
  PreferredSizeWidget sappBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, actions: [
      Builder(builder: (context) {
        exController = ExpandableController.of(context, required: true)!;
        lvController.addListener(listenScrolling);
        return IconButton(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.rectangle_compress_vertical),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                exController.toggle();
              });
            });
      }),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/mlitchard/transparency_demo.git) to the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `buildList()` method inside the `Stack` widget and remove the color from `Container` with the `testCard()` function.

```dart
Container(
  color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: sappBar(context),
    body: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        buildList(),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Expandable(
              collapsed: Container(),
              expanded: testCard(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Where did the other widget go? I want to be able to see it, and not have it obscured by the ListView.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, just updated my answer.

Comment: I had arrived at the answer due to your first attempt. I removed that answer, to upvote your final one. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you also.